Geometry nodes - Extrude along a Poli curve path
I´m trying to recreate this tutorial in Blender 4.2 without success. I don´t know if the problem was in the Sample Index node. I need sharp corners without distortion. Any clue?

file

As far as I can see, you've actually done everything right. But what's missing in this case is the correct alignment of the normal of the curve. To do this, use the node Set Curve Normal and insert it at the very beginning after Object Info.

Hi man, thank you! It works like a charm!
